# MySQL query on parent in joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

I stuck on a "simple" MySQL query and I am not able to find a suitable keyword for search engines for my problem, so I hope there is someone who can tell me how to achieve the following challenge.

I have 3 Tables.

The first one holds users. Just a simple like this:

Table: User

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Sally |
| 3 | Fred |

The next holds some data (lets say a calendar), where each entry has an owner related to 'User'

Table Calendar:

| Id | Name | Date | OwnerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Soccer | 2021-08-01 | 3 |
| 2 | Cinema | 2021-09-12 | 2 |
| 3 | Dinner | 2021-09-04 | 2 |
| 4 | Barbeque | 2021-07-16 | 1 |
| 5 | ... | ... |  |

.. and so on

Now we have a third table which enables the user to share their calendar, entry by entry

Table: CalendarUser

| CalendarId | UserId | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | * Fred's soccer date is shared with John |
| 2 | 3 | * Sally's Cinema date is shared with Fred |
| 2 | 1 | * and shared with John |

.. and so on

You can assume that the schema has valid constraints, indexer, primary keys and relations.

What I want to archive is to query all entries of a specific user (owner) and all entries which are shared by this user by User.Name

What I have now is:

```
SELECT 
      Calendar.Id,
      Calendar.Name,
      Calendar.Date
      
FROM Calendar      

left join User          on Calendar.OwnerId = User.Id

left join CalendarUser  on     Calendar.Id = CalendarUser.CalendarId   
                           and User.Id     = User.Id

where

(
      (User.Name = "John") 
  OR ( ?????     = "John")  

)
```

This way I get the entry where John is the owner. What do I have to add, that the query returns the entries which are shared with John, too?

The result should look like this:

| Id | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Soccer | 2021-08-01 |
| 2 | Cinema | 2021-09-12 |
| 4 | Barbeque | 2021-07-16 |

Thank you very much for assistance!

Comment: You must select from the users table again to get the invitee. Please see my answer on this. As to the owner: You are using an outer join here. Why? Can there even be calendar entries without an owner?

Comment: No, each entry has an owner specified in OwnerId column. Not using "left join" delivered not the expected result. I have transferred your answer to my query (using left join) and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the tables. As there is an owner and an invited person, you'll have to join the users table twice. Then see that either the owner or the invited person is John.

```
select
  owner.name as owner_name,
  c.name as calender_entry,
  invited.name as invited_name,
  cu.comment as invitation_comment
from calendar c
join users owner on owner.id = c.ownerid
left join calendaruser cu on cu.calendarid = c.id
left join users invited on invited.id = cu.userid
where owner.name = 'John' or invited.name = 'John'
order by c.date;
```